# Почему не работает код? Эзотерический язык на питоне

Tags: python

Не выводит резльтат([документация](https://github.com/kislball/PseudoHack/blob/master/README.md) языка(не питон)) Например в script.ph содержится 
hackType pentagon;
connect pentagon;
hack;

С помощью рандома при выполнении команды "connect pentagon;" должно вывести: "Connected!" или "Ah! Cool protection!"
Потом с помощью великого рандома при выполнении команды должно выдать "HACKED THIS SITE" или "oh ................ FBI OPEN UP!"
В итоге ничего не выводится. Вопрос: почему? Ошибок змейка не выдает.
[Сам код](https://github.com/kislball/PseudoHack/blob/master/language.py)

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [ask]

Comment: Если нужно исправить ошибку, постарайтесь ее локализовать или хотя бы подробно описать. На каких данных программа работает неправильно и как именно она это делает?

Comment: Извинюсь, исправил. Просто на стаке только сегодня зарегистрировался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для двух-сложных команд, как `hackType ppp`, `connect ppp`, замените операторы проверки с `==` на `startswith`:

```
if code[i].startswith('hackType'):
```